How to create advanced visualization in Kibana Dashboard
I'm new to Elastic/Kibana. Most example visualizations I've seen are relatively simple. I'm trying to create a table that's relatively complex.
My input data is available as a Data View in the below form. Note that {person,run_id,node_id} uniquely defines the rows.
person,run_id,node_id,units

I want to produce a table as a kibana visualization showing the percent growth in total units, between the two most recent runs. Something like
person,highest_recent_run_id,second_highest_recent_run_id,most_recent_total_units,second_most_recent_total_units,growth_percent
jim, 312, 305, 1060, 1000, 6%
mary, ...
...

How can I do this? Is this reasonable to do in Kibana?
